# Multicolumn CSS min-height 100%

Tags: css, height, multiple-columns

I followed this [**guide**](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) to help setup the columns for my page.

What I'm trying to do is to make the my columns fill the screen if the screen is larger than the content, but when the content is longer than the browser screen can show at once, use the default overflow scroll or auto.

Currently, I have the body, my container (a div around the containers described in the article), and the containers described in the article set to height: 100%. This is fine when the page fits all the content, but when the screen is too small, the content just cuts off.

I tried fixing this by changing the body or my container to min-height to 100% and although this makes the smaller screen show everything again, in the larger screens, the 2 columns "backgrounds" do not extend to the bottom of the page, but my container does.

Edit: my html and body are also set to height 100% currently.

Edit2: here's a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8DNmh/1/) for what it looks like when the content is larger than the screen

Now the structure is something like:

```
body (height: 100%)
    my_container (height: 100%)
        container2 (height: 100%)
            container1 (height: 100%)
                column1
                column2
```

I'd like it do be something like

```
body
    my_container (min-height: 100%)
        container2 (height: 100%)
            container1 (height: 100%)
                column1
                column2
```

Comment: Can you confirm you want your my_container to be bigger than 100%?

Comment: Have you set both `html` and `body` to `height: 100%` in the CSS? Like so `html,body{height:100%;}`.

Comment: Yes, if necessary, I would like my_container to be bigger than 100%. And I have set html,body{height: 100%}

Comment: The guide you follow writes "try exposing this rule only to IE with IE conditional comments", was written in 2008 and doesn't tell once which version of IE it can be. At the time 6 and/or 7? Beware not to aim IE8 and IE9 when you really want to debug IE7 and/or 6 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove height: 100%; from your CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/8DNmh/2/